# How to publish Blazor webapp to Azure

Tags: azure, github, blazor

Can anyone please help with the following.

I am just starting out with Blazor (using Visual Studio 2019). I have followed an online tutorial and have a trival app working locally (just selected the Blazor project type when I created a new project in Visual Studio and built it and now it's running at https://localhost:44311/ on IIS (as long as the project is debugging) ).

If I now right click on the project and select "Publish", and then I select "Azure App Service" and then I click "Publish", then Visual Studio hangs forever with a spinning wait cursor saying "Loading subscriptions". If I look under View -> Cloud Explorer and click the Account Management icon, I see my account is there, so that's fine.

I normally develop my webapps with Node and my preferred workflow is to write the Javascript code in Visual Studio and then use git cli to update a git repository which is linked to an Azure webapp which automatically builds when I commit code. Could I do the same with my razor app? If so, which files from the Razor app directory (wwwroot?) would I need to add to a new github repository and commit in order to then create a new web service through the Azure portal to then link to that github project?

As long as I get one way working to publish the app that would be great.

Thanks for any help,
Mitch.

Comment: check this one https://timheuer.com/blog/deploy-blazor-webassembly-applications-on-azure-using-github-actions-wasm/

Comment: Do you have an account on dev.azure.com ?   There you can set up a CI/CD pipeline. I think there is a free-as-in-beer option.

Comment: I had this also, so I created the resources in azure portal and then use the existing resources in vs, what worked.